# Mongoose Nodejs Parent model with the count of an indefinite amount of children

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I have 2 mongoose models. One is the parent and the other is the child. The child will hold the ref Id to the parent model. I did this because there is an indefinite amount of children that could be "attached" to the parent. Is there a way that when I run a query to get the parent model that it can come with the count of how many children are tied it.

```js
const parentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    prop1: {
        type: String
    },
    childCount:{
        type: Number
    }
});

const childSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    prop1: {
        type: String
    },
    parentId:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Parent"
    }
});
```

It would be very useful if I could call parentModel.findById() and it come with the count of all "Child" models that have the parentId on it. To clarify I do not want the child model in the parent model as an array because it is an indefinite amount of children.

```js
const parent = parentModel.findById(id);

console.log(parent.childCount) // 2354
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `childCount` from your parent schema and query the `childSchema` with the parent `id` so that you can get your count.

```
await childSchema.countDocuments({ parentId: idOfParent })
```

If you want it fast to run fast, also add an index. This will enable the count to be run against the index rather than scanning the whole collection one by one [(IXSCAN vs COLLSCAN)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/).

```
const childSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  prop1: {
    type: String,
  },
  parentId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Parent',
  },
});

childSchema.index({ parentId: 1 });
```

EDIT:

If you want to get the count of children for each parent. You need to use an [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) otherwise it gonna be a nightmare.

```
await childSchema
  .aggregate()
  .group({ _id: '$parentId', countOfChildrenPerParent: { $sum: 1 } })
  .exec();
```

Comment: hmm ya thats what I am kind of already trying to do. I just didn't know if there was a way to do that without calling the db again. If I end up querying like 1000 parent documents then I have to run a for loop over the 1000 docs to get their count of children. Just was curious if mongo/mongoose could handle that in a more optimized way for me.

Comment: thanks for the index idea, I always forget about that option. That should help speed it up more for sure.

Comment: @CodyWHageman please check updated answer to avoid doing a loop that goes back to the DB each time.

Comment: Nice i'll give this a shot, Thank you!

Comment: would it be possible to use $lookup to that count when i use aggregate on the parentModel..LIke parentModel.aggregate([{$lookup: {from:"childModel", ...etc}]

Comment: Yes you could. But do no forget that MongoDB at heart is a non relational database system. I'm personally slightly reluctant to use whatever kind of `JOIN` like `$lookup`. But of course, it always depends of your use case.

Comment: I understand that but how do you avoid that in this situation.

Comment: Why do you need data from both collection at the same time? Understanding the use-case would help giving a more appropriate answer. Maybe initial design needs rethink or maybe MongoDB is not the database system suitable to your use-case? For example, about a REST API, I would separate ressources and would never need data from both tables at same time. Something else to look into are [Views](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/) if you always need both.